# Control irrigation pump

Tags: well-pump, irrigation

I'm converting my irrigation system from a physical timer with physical valves to electronic control with solenoid valves.

Previously the pump would turn on automatically by the physical timer, which would cause the physical valves to switch between irrigation zones each time the system turned off/on.

I'm now at the point at which I have a basic 3-zone controller wired up to valves. However, I realize now that I need the ability to turn on/off the pump. Additionally, I believe that when a valve inevitably gets stuck closed, the pump needs to automatically turn off.

What pieces do I need to 1) have the irrigation controller control a 230V pump, and 2) prevent the pump from running if the valve doesn't open?

Comment: Check controller for a “master valve” option. Use this with relay to switch pump.

Comment: fwiw, an electronic ball valve will be more reliable than solenoids, especially when you don't have city pressure on them, which many cheaper valves need to operate. Ball valves also don't need pressure or power to stay latched, which reduces the potential for situations like you're worried about as the pump and valve don't need tight correlation, timing, or have mutual dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2: overpressure cutout. (backed up with mechanical overpressure relief valve in case that fails. Cutout operates well below relief valve pressure. Relief valve pressure lower than pipe max pressure.)

1: suitable relay/contactor